# Display rows based on sql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using caldera forms in my WordPress site to collect data for new admissions for our club. Form functions as expected. I am trying to view a list of open applications and a page to view them. Following is my SQL table tor entries (`cf_form_entries`).

```
+----+-----------------+--------+
| ID | Form ID         | Status |
+----+-----------------+--------+
| 1  | CF5852c23e56b1d | active |
+----+-----------------+--------+
| 2  | CF5852c23e56b1d | active |
+----+-----------------+--------+
| 3  | CF5852c23e56b1d | active |
+----+-----------------+--------+
```

Following table contains all the information submitted by the form (`cf_form_entry_values`);

```
+----+----------+---------------+--------------------+
| id | entry_id |     slug      |       value        |
+----+----------+---------------+--------------------+
|  1 |        1 | branch        | Branch A           |
|  2 |        1 | full_name     | asdasd asdasd      |
|  3 |        1 | email_address | b2196363@trbvn.com |
|  4 |        1 | phone         | 111111111          |
|  5 |        2 | branch        | Branch A           |
|  6 |        2 | full_name     | Full Name          |
|  7 |        2 | email_address | asdasd@asdas.com   |
|  8 |        2 | phone         | 111111111          |
|  9 |        3 | branch        | Branch A           |
| 10 |        3 | full_name     | Namwe              |
| 11 |        3 | email_address | wert@wertwert.com  |
| 12 |        3 | phone         | 111111111          |
+----+----------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I can run a simple `select` query and get the open application details of a given branch, inner joining tables.

```
SELECT cf_form_entries.id,
       cf_form_entries.form_id,
       cf_form_entries.status,
       cf_form_entry_values.slug,
       cf_form_entry_values.value
FROM cf_form_entry_values
  INNER JOIN cf_form_entries
     ON cf_form_entry_values.entry_id = cf_form_entries.id
WHERE cf_form_entry_values.slug = 'branch'
   AND cf_form_entry_values.value LIKE '%Branch A%'
```

Above query results in the following table;

```
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+----------+
| id |     form_id     | status |  slug  |  value   |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 | CF5852c23e56b1d | active | branch | Branch A |
|  3 | CF5852c23e56b1d | active | branch | Branch A |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

My question is, **How can I display (echo) the other details such as the name, email address, etc. of the selected tables?**

As such my end result shall display all details of the open applications in a table. (not just the branch name)

I tried a while loop. But I can only echo the branch names as they are the only data selected in my inner joined table.

Comment: These records name, email address, etc. are in which table?

Comment: @AmitKumarSahu, Like I said, they are in the `cf_form_entry_values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fe.id, fe.form_id, fe.status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fev.slug = 'branch' THEN fev.value END) as branch,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fev.slug = 'full_name' THEN fev.value END) as full_name,
       . . .
FROM cf_form_entries fe INNER JOIN
     cf_form_entry_values fev
     ON fev.entry_id = fe.id
GROUP BY fe.id, fe.form_id, fe.status;
```

The nice thing about this approach is that adding a new value only requires adding a new expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Seems fine. How can I add `WHERE`, so that I can select results owing to one branch?

Comment: I tried adding where and ended up with an empty result. Considering using `HAVING` instead

Comment: @Sid . . . `HAVING branch = ??`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Query By Using LEFT JOIN ON Two Tables.

```
SELECT cfev.*,cfm.Form ID as entry_id 
     FROM cf_form_entry_values cfev 
         LEFT JOIN cf_form_entries cfm ON cfm.id = cfev.entry_id 
             WHERE cfev .slug = 'branch' AND vfm.value LIKE '%Branch A%'
```

This Might Be Helpful. And You Get Proper Output...

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the first two values, and you can use the same pattern for the rest:

```
SELECT entries.id,
       entries.form_id,
       entries.status,
       (SELECT value FROM cf_form_entry_values as v 
        WHERE slug='branch' and entry_id=entries.entry_id) as branch,
       (SELECT value FROM cf_form_entry_values as v 
        WHERE slug='full_name' and entry_id=entries.entry_id) as full_name
FROM cf_form_entry_values
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM cf_form_entry_values
  INNER JOIN cf_form_entries
    ON cf_form_entry_values.entry_id = cf_form_entries.id
  WHERE cf_form_entry_values.slug = 'branch'
    AND cf_form_entry_values.value LIKE '%Branch A%'
  ) as entries
  ON cf_form_entry_values.entry_id = entries.id
GROUP BY cf_form_entries.id
```